# Angular, show selected option in textbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a multiple columns table and showing their values in multiple controls by Angular JS. For example I am using Select/Option (multiple) to show column A, and I want to use another text box to show column B, based on select/option. Here is code:

Column A in Select (multiple):

```
<select multiple data-ng-model="selectedEmp" data-ng-options="o.emp for o in post.Emps" >
    <option value="SampleValue">Samplevalue</option>
</select>
```

Column B in text box:

```
<input data-ng-model="selectedEmp.gender" type="text"  style="width:60px;"> </input>
```

The thing is, when I am not using 'Multiple' in select control, the gender value (in same record) can be displayed in text box, but when using 'multiple', the text box is not showing selected current record.

Please help on how to implement this.

Thanks

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: What do you get in textbox in case of multiple?

Comment: just updated my question with missing code sample

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `select` without using `multiple`, you are binding to a object. So your `selectedEmp` might be something like `{"emp":1,"gender":"M"}` (an object).

But when you use `multiple` select, you are binding to an array. So your `selectedEmp` might be something like :
`[{"emp":1,"gender":"M"},{"emp":2,"gender":"F"}]`. Notice the `[]`.

So, in case of `multiple`, you also need to pass the index whose value you want to bind. But in this case, it seems like you want to have `input`'s for multiple selected items from above `select`.

I would use something like this:

`<input data-ng-model="s.gender" type="text" ng-repeat="s in selectedEmp" />`

Comment: The reason I am using 'Multiple' is I want the Select as a 'List' instead of drop down box. I am still using the single selection actually. I just want to the input box showing the currenct (single selected) corresponding gender.

Comment: You want to use single select but want to display it as a List(Multiple select) in UI ? You can achieve this but that could confuse your users? Why don't you create a custom directive for it?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work ? Can you create a plunker/fiddle with `post.Emps` ?

Comment: I am sure you can find tons of tutorials on directives on Internet. Here's the official one https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive